# OpenCV java как разделить слитные контуры

Tags: java, алгоритм, opencv

[image: Оригинал]
[image: После Thresholding]
[image: Contours]

У меня есть проект по распознаванию чисел.

Я хочу выделить каждую цифру, но есть близко находящиеся числа, которые я хочу разделить. Как можно разделить такие числа?

Answer (score 2):

В данном случае должна помочь [морфологическая операция opening](https://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d9/d61/tutorial_py_morphological_ops.html) - комбинация эрозии и дилатации. Первый этап удалит отдельные точки и тонкие мостики, второй восстановит общие очертания в несколько сглаженном виде без этих деталей.

Конечно, при этом какие-то фигуры могут рассыпаться на части (например, из за дефектов в правой пятёрке). Нужно смотреть, поможет ли предварительный closing для уничтожения дефектов, или приведёт к неубиваемым мостикам-спайкам.

Вообще для таких изображений анализируют объекты и строят решётку - цифры же определённого размера и положение их не случайно, в таком случае разделение производится по границам ячеек/ограничивающих прямоугольников.

Answer (score 1):

Я не знаю как называется этот способ, он основан на построении гистограммы изображения, и поиске локальных минимумов, но сначала нужно найти и залить все замкнутые области.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```js
let img = new Image();
img.crossOrigin = 'anonymous';
img.src = 'https://i.imgur.com/EqAIRNx.png';

let srcCtx = src.getContext('2d'),
    gistCtx = gist.getContext('2d');

img.onload = function() {
  src.width = gist.width = img.width;
  src.height = gist.height = img.height;
  srcCtx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
  let imgData = srcCtx.getImageData(0, 0, img.width, img.height)
  let gistData = Array(img.width).fill(0);
  for(var x = 0; x<img.width; x++) 
    for(var y = 0; y<img.height; y++) 
      gistData[x] += imgData.data[(y*img.width + x)*4]>10 ? 1 : 0;
  gistData.forEach((e,i) => line(gistCtx, i, e))
  gistCtx.strokeStyle = srcCtx.strokeStyle = 'red';
  extrem(gistData, 12).min
    .map(e => Math.floor(e[0]/2 + e[1]/2))
    .forEach((e, i) => {
      line(gistCtx, e, img.height)
      line(srcCtx, e, img.height)
    })
}

function line(ctx, x, h) {
    ctx.beginPath(); 
    ctx.moveTo(x, img.height);
    ctx.lineTo(x, img.height - h);
    ctx.stroke();
}

function extrem(y, eps) {
    let s,M,m,j, i=0, min=[], max=[],
        greater = a => a >= M - eps,
        lesser = a => a <= m + eps;
    for (; i < y.length; i++) {
        if (s && M - eps <= y[i]) 
          M = Math.max(M, y[i])
        else if (!s && m + eps >= y[i]) 
          m = Math.min(m, y[i]) 
        else if (s) 
          m = iter(max, greater)     
        else 
          M = iter(min, lesser)   
    }
    return {min, max};
    
    function iter(arr, cond) {
      j = i - 1;
      while (cond(y[j])) j--;
      arr.push([j, i]);
      s = !s;
      return y[i];
    }
}
```

```html
<img src="https://i.imgur.com/EqAIRNx.png" style="margin-bottom:40px">
<div style="display:inline-block">
<canvas id="src"></canvas><br>
<canvas id="gist"></canvas>
</div>
```

PS: похоже что при помощи нахождения минимумов построчно и вращении исходного изображения можно еще найти на сколько нужно повернуть картинку, чтобы текст встал четко по горизонтали.